# How to create a MQQueueManager object in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, ibm-mq

I need some help to understand why my library not working for `MQQUEUEMANAGER`.

This is my code :

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

Hashtable mqProps = new Hashtable();
mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "my_channel");
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, my_port);
mqProps.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "my_host");
mqProps.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "my_user_id");
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "my_password");

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("my_QM", mqProps);

vars.putObject("QMGR", qMgr);
```

I imported the following library : `com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.3.0`

But I have an error :

```
Target exception: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Hashtable; import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager; import com.ibm.mq. . . . '' at line number 14
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Hashtable; import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager; import com.ibm.mq. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Object constructor : at Line: 14 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Hashtable; import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager; import com.ibm.mq. . . . '' : new MQQueueManager ( "my_QM" , mqProps )
```

Do I need to use another specific param in the constructor?

Do you have any idea why JMeter generate an error?

Comment: JMeter didn't generate this error, the queue manager did. It also wrote information about why it generated this error in it's AMQERR01.LOG file. Please look in there and update your question withe the details from the error message if you requires further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Target exception: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code
> '2', Reason '2035'.

MQ Reason Code of [2035 (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=troubleshooting-return-code-2035-mqrc-not-authorized) means that the UserId that the application is using does not have permission to connect to the queue manager.

> mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "my_channel");

"my_channel" is a sample but make sure it does not begin with "SYSTEM".  You should be using your own uniquely named channel.

> mqProps.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "my_user_id");
> mqProps.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "my_password");

Do those credentials exist on the remote server, so that the queue manager can authenticate those credentials?  Have you given that UserId permission to connect to the queue manager?  i.e. using [setmqaut command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=reference-setmqaut-grant-revoke-authority)

What about giving permission to the UserId to open the queue(s)?  (again with [setqmaut command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=reference-setmqaut-grant-revoke-authority)).

It is always best to grant permission to the UserId's group rather than the UserId (aka principle).

```
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -t qmgr -g {GROUP} +connect +inq +dsp
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -n ABC.** -t queue -g {GROUP} +allmqi +dsp
```

Note: The "**" wildcard is correct.  IBM MQ makes a distinction between "*" and "**" wildcards.

Those 2 setmqaut commands will:

- set permissions for connecting to a queue manager and
- set permissions for opening all queues that begin with "ABC."

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you're using [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) and this is not something you should be doing as [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)
2. If despite this you are still willing to use Beanshell be aware that it masks the problem so you either need to put [`debug();` operator](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html#debug) somewhere in "your" script (however it looks like taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39930356/2897748))or surround your code into [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

   ```
   try {
       //the code you copied and pasted without understanding what it is doing
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       log.error("Failure in the copied and pasted script", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

   this way you will see more human-friendly stacktrace in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and will be able to figure out what is the root cause of the issue

I don't see any problems with the code, it works okay even with Beanshell, here is the evidence:

[image]

You may also find [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article useful.